# Is there any way to get a "logical stacktrace" from Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle build that is failing because something is going wrong in one of the build steps.  This particular step is not relevant to what I'm working on, and someone else is fixing it, but I'd rather not be held up waiting on them.

I've deleted the only reference to this step as a dependency of the core build in my build.gradle file... *but it's still running!*  I tried running with the `--stacktrace` option, but all that gave me was a JVM stacktrace of Gradle's internal stack at the point where things failed, which is basically useless to me.

What I'd like is some actual useful information, a "stack trace" of the dependency chain that led to this step being included in the build process.  Is there any way to get Gradle to give that to me?

Comment: Why is `--debug` insufficient?

Comment: What is the step you are referring to, a Gradle task? Is it failing in configuration or in execution step?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to see the dependency of tasks that will be executed.
In that case you could help yourself with using the following plugin https://gitlab.com/barfuin/gradle-taskinfo#gradle-taskinfo.
As such a graph is not provided out of the box from Gradle itself.

Include plugin

```
plugins {
    id 'org.barfuin.gradle.taskinfo' version '1.0.5'
}
```

Then execute it to show task dependency tree (replacing task name with actual one)

```
./gradlew tiTree your_task_name
```